# Proving strong pseudoprimality

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, modular-arithmetic, pseudoprimes

Let $n$ be a Fermat-pseudoprime with respect to 2. Show that $2^n-1$ is a strong pseudoprime with respect to 2.

I tried solving the problem as follows. Since $n$ is a Fermat-pseudoprime with respect to 2, it holds that $2^{n-1}\equiv 1\mod n$, so $n$ divides $2^{n-1}-1$. Therefore, since $2^n\equiv1\mod 2^n-1$, we have, by raising both sides of the equivalence to a suitable power, that $2^{2^{n-1}-1}\equiv 1\mod2^n-1$. This implies exactly that $2^n-1$ is a strong pseudoprime with respect to 2, since $(2^n-1)-1=2(2^{n-1}-1)$.

Is this attempt correct? Also, how do I prove that $2^n-1$ is not a prime?

Comment: See [this duplicate](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2176998/show-that-every-composite-fermat-number-is-a-pseudoprime-base-2).

Comment: Yes, it is correct.

Answer (score 1):

It is correct. Suppose $d$ divides $n$, since $n$ is assumed to be nonprime. Then $2^d-1$ divides $2^n-1$, so $2^n-1$ is not prime.