# Proving that each Fermat number is prime iff $F_n | 3^{\frac{F_n-1}{2}}+1$.

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, modular-arithmetic, fermat-numbers

I am getting into a bit of number theory and came up with the following exercise:

**Exercise.** Show that each Fermat number is prime **iff**   $F_n | 3^{\frac{F_n-1}{2}}+1$.

My only idea follows (it is not a complete resolution).

**Idea.** If $F_n | 3^{\frac{F_n-1}{2}}+1$ then $$3^{\frac{F_n-1}{2}}+1 \equiv 0 \hspace{.3cm}(\text{mod} F_n) \Leftrightarrow 3^{\frac{F_n-1}{2}} \equiv -1 \hspace{.3cm}(\text{mod} F_n)$$
My next step was to consider $F_n = 2^{2^n}+1$. This means that $\frac{F_n-1}{2} = 2^{2^n-1}$ and thus the above is equivalent to:
$$ 3^{2^{2^n-1}} \equiv -1 \hspace{.3cm} (\text{mod} F_n)$$
But now I don't know how to proceed further on. I have thought about raising the congruence to some exponent (this technique can be seen here: [Show that every composite Fermat number is a pseudoprime base 2.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2176998/show-that-every-composite-fermat-number-is-a-pseudoprime-base-2)) but haven't been able to came up with a solution.

Thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: This is called Pepin's test. Searching on that name will easily locate proofs - as will searching on "fermat number" "primality test". One should always search before posting questions.

Comment: @BillDubuque you'd be out of a job if we did.

Comment: @BillDubuque Thanks for the help. English is not my native language so sometimes it's hard to find the correct words to search for. Roddy got some jokes ;) !

Comment: @roro This "joke" is similar to the joke that doctors would have no work if noone would get ill. In this case, I clearly agree Bill since this is a very famous criterion for Fermat numbers that can easily be googled.

Comment: I agree with Bill aswell! He is absolutely right, I just found some fun about Roddy's comment :D